# How to generate the association rules from the initial frequent itemset coming from the support ?

Tags: apriori

I am currently trying to find a strong association rule for the confidence from the frequent itemsets that I have obtained through the support algorithm in c#. Sorry guys I do not have any valuable piece of code at the moment but anything will be welcome. For more explanations see the table at the bottom of the page. I would like any hints on the implementation of how to generate the final frequent itemsets based on the confidence.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70371/Apriori-Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

the **1. generation of association rules** and the **2. extraction of strong association rules** of a set of frequent itemsets is quite simple:

1. `x` is a `frequent itemset` of a set of `frequent itemsets` `{x, y, z, ...}`. out of each each frequent itemset `{x, y, z, ...}` are association rules to generate. so for `x`. an `association rule` is `a -> b`. whereby `b` is any `b ⊂ x`, and `a` is `x - b`.

**-> association rule generated.**

2. if the `confidence` of an `association rule` `a -> b` is `greater than or equal` to the set `confidence level` then the `association rule` is a `strong association rule`. i.e. `support(x) / support(a) ≥ confidence level`.

**-> strong association rule extracted.**

Comment: Thank you ! Very good explanation on the concept of the association rule but my concern was geared toward generating the association rule of a frequent itemset. I was looking for any particular way to implement an algorithm in other to have those 2^n-2 different association rule.

Comment: i'm afraid i don't get your question straight. could you please give an example of what you like to achieve.